# Outlook 2010 Block Email by IP Address

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, ip-address, spam-prevention

I have Outlook 2010.  Is it possible to block incoming email using its IP Address?

I have had a look at filters and the Junk Emal settings, but cannot find a specific IP Address filter.

Question: What, if anything, have I missed with IP Address blocking in Outlook 2010?

Comment: I can see the domain name and email address settings, but what I am looking for is an 'IP Address' handle. I would be happy to send offending emails to the Junk Mail folder rather than delete them.

Comment: You can't block spam by IP because there're thousands upon thousands of zombie computers sending out spam to the entire world. Blocking 1 IP won't prevent you from getting spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Microsoft Outlook Version has such a blocking feature. To manage your spam, you will have to use any Spam Filter.

If you're using Smarter Mails or Exchange, you can manage your spam there, or you can install any third-party spam filter locally.

Comment: I do not think this is quite true, see http://www.slipstick.com/rules/junkmail.asp

Comment: Please read article carefully with that you can only manage your junk mails or spam mails, that you can forward to one specific folder using rules and alerts. But you can not block them.

Comment: It must only have become available in 2010: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/add-names-to-the-junk-e-mail-filter-lists-HA010355043.aspx